# JavaScript Remoting calls not working from Page contentType="text/javascript"

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, remote-action

I am searching for a solution to **use a page as javascript and to make the remote action calls to the server**.
Here is the code of the page that I created

```
 <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showChat="false" showHeader="false" Controller="CustomerOrderCtrl" 
    sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" contentType="text/javascript">

    var service = angular.module("ctrl1Service_PK", []);

    service.factory('CustomerInfoService', ['$q', function ($q) {
        return {
            EditCustomerDetails: function (customerId) {
                customerId = window.btoa(customerId);
                console.log(customerId);
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                // make AJAX request to the remote service
                var abc;

                console.log(Visualforce.remoting.Manager.getController('CustomerOrderCtrl'));


                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.CustomerOrderCtrl.getCustomer}', customerId, function(result, event) {
                    if(event.type == 'exception') {
                        deferred.reject(event.message);
                    } else {
                        var customer = window.atob(result);
                        var find = '\'';
                        var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
                        customer = customer.replace(re, '');
                        deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(customer));
                    }
                }, {
                    escape: true
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    }]);
</apex:page>
```

---

Controller class

```
@RemoteAction
global static String getCustomer(String customerId){
    //Some code here
    return BPUtility.getEncodedString('');


}
```

I am getting this error

> Unable to invoke action 'CustomerOrderCtrl.getCustomer': no controller
>   and/or function found

Comment: did you try by removing or changing content-type?

Comment: I want to use the page as javascript that's why I specified the contentType="text/javascript"

Comment: Never seen anyone using `contentType="text/javascript"`, What is the use case? Maybe you should try using Visualforce Components.

Comment: I want to load the js at runtime using require js

Comment: Its okay to use content-type but did you check by removing the content-type to make sure this attribute is the reason?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the content type and put the code in script tag then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try removing remote action and {! / }  :  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('CustomerOrderCtrl.getCustomer'',

In other words you want to call a remote actions from a page without a controller, like a static resource.
[Javascript Remoting in Static Resource](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20616/javascript-remoting-in-static-resource)

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

@hitesh-gupta i would do the following based on W3C standards.

**Question/Clarification:**

Based on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm there is no contentType attribute called `text/javascript`, so not sure if it is supported by Salesforce.

You might want to refer the available  type attributes here [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp]

FYI based on IANA, `text/javascript` is OBSOLETE, refer the below link
http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

**Solution:**

So you VF page should have the below

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showChat="false" showHeader="false" Controller="CustomerOrderCtrl" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" contentType="application/javascript">
```

Let me know if it helps.