# How to control LWC styling dynamically?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I need different widths for my LWC for lightning and classic(lightning out) as my LWC is shooting out of card width in lightning.

I am able to know whether a user is in lightning or classic using wire and apex. How can I use it to dynamically control the width of LWC?

[image: LWC shoots out]

APEX

```java
public with sharing class ThemeTest {
    @auraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getUIThemeDescription() {
        String theme = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
        return theme;
    }
}
```

This is how I get the context. (I want to set the component width here)

```js
    @wire(getUITheme) theme({error,data}){
        if(data==='Theme4d'){             
            this.isLightning=true; 
        }  
        if(error){             
            this.error1 = error; 
        }                     
    }
```

HTML

```html
<div id="setWidth" class="slds-scrollable" style="height:20rem;width:66rem">
                    <lightning-datatable 
                        key-field="Id"
                        data={wrappers}
                        columns={columns}
                        onrowaction={navigateToRecordViewPage}
                        hide-checkbox-column="true">
                    </lightning-datatable>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use media queries to get device-width then set the width of LWC based device width.

Comment: Good to see you [looked](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238489/detecting-ui-theme-from-javascript-static-resource) for existing solutions. I would say that you should update your question to include a bit more code detail - for example, how you import the getUITheme wire.

Comment: I added the apex code above. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [flexipageRegionWidth](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_width_aware).

> ## Make a Component Width-Aware
>
> When you add a component to a region on a page in the Lightning App Builder, use `@api flexipageRegionWidth` to
>   pass the region’s width to the component. Then with some strategic
>   CSS, you can tell the component to render in different ways in
>   different regions at run time.
>
> **Valid CSS class values are SMALL, MEDIUM, and LARGE**

**JS**:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class TestClass extends LightningElement {
    @api flexipageRegionWidth = 'CLASSIC'; // default to classic. If its lightning, framework will set the value
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<template>
   <div class={flexipageRegionWidth}>
       <datatable>
   </div>
</template>
```

**CSS:**

```
div .CLASSIC {
    width: 66rem;
    ...
}
div .LARGE {
    width: 40rem;
    ...
}
div .SMALL {
    width: 15rem;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works! It takes `div .CLASSIC` value for classic(lightning out) and sets width in lightning by itself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any option to do the same in the lightning communities? I have a component on the login page and even though it takes by default 1/3 of the whole page, slds sees the screen as large, so i cannot use slds for small/medium/large devices.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `template if:true={property}` expression to show different divs based on logic.

Here's a trailhead [tutorial.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/add-styles-and-data-to-a-lightning-web-component)

Another example:

```
<template if:false={moveToNextPage}>
    <div class={tableClass}>

    </div>
</template>
```

---

```
  @api
    controlTableOff() {
        this.tableClass = 'slds-hide';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!
Yes, I can use `template if:true={isLightning}` and `template if:false={isLightning}`, but I'll have to insert same datatable twice (with different widths) for lightning and classic. It doesn't seem like a good way of programming. Hence I was looking to set the CSS component width through javascript itself.

Comment: I think you can just change the div's class as a dynamic property thus not making use of two tables?

Comment: How do I do that? I cannot use `element = document.getElementById('div1');`. I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576927/how-to-dynamically-change-css-class-of-div-tag)

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution is to stop using fixed width (you use 66rem) and to use min/max widths plus a standard width of 100% which will try to fill the width of the container by default.

Comment: `datatable` uses 100% of width by default