# How to use SLDS responsive sizes when an LWC is in a multi-column page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, flexipages, slds-grid, responsive-design

The [size breakpoints in SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/#Responsive-Layout-Options) are based on the screen size which works great for LWCs that occupy the full width of the screen e.g.:

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_1-of-3">
    ...
</div>
```

But I'd like my LWC to layout correctly when it is in (flexi-) pages that present it in 2 or 3 or 4 columns side by side where the relevant width is only a part of the screen.

Any suggestions for how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this related mechanism [Make a Component Width-Aware](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_width_aware) is the only mechanism available:

```
@api flexipageRegionWidth;
```

It reports the flexi-page "region’s width" as:

- SMALL
- MEDIUM
- LARGE

and you can use this name as a CSS style or otherwise react to the value such as using different SLDS classes. So a bit of work. See [How to control LWC styling dynamically?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284137/how-to-control-lwc-styling-dynamically).

*But this is only a relative indication i.e. the relative size in page builder; the values do not change as the page is resized.*